# Cycle through input fields and keep keyboard open

Tags: flutter

I have a form with multiple text fields and would like users to be able to jump to the next input field when tapping "enter" on the on-screen keyboard.

I have been able to make it work by requesting focus for the next field's `FocusNode` in my field's `onFieldSubmitted` handler:

```
new TextFormField(
  ...
  onFieldSubmitted: (newValue) {
    ...
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(
      widget.nextNode ?? new FocusNode()
    );
 }
```

This works, but you do briefly see the on-screen keyboard close and re-open. Is there a way in Flutter to keep the keyboard on the screen until `widget.nextNode` becomes `null`?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below parameter to TextFormField.

```
    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
```